# Class Function is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, function, class

I am creating a game engine for HTML5 Canvas with javascript for personal use, however I am running into a problem. I have created a entities class with a super constructor and a few functions (like remove and add new entities) as well as a update and init function within the class. However when I run the main init at the end of the code, with entities.init(); it reports an error and says it is not a function, even though I'm sure I made it public. Here is the code

```
function entities(){
//Entities class holds all objects that: take damage, move,and do things that a static object could not.//
    //A list of all current entities in game//
var entitiesList = new Array();

//Allows removal of an entitiy from the game, and the current list of entities//
function removeEntity( id){
    //snip!//
}

//entity superclass//
function entity( name, spriteName, HP){
    //snip!//
    var updateEntity = new function(){
        console.log("UPDATING Entities")
        //drawSprite(sprite, posX, posY);
        if(this.timer > 0){
            this.timer = this.timer - 1;
        }else{
            removeEntity(this.entityID);
            delete this;
        }
        if(this.health == 0){
            removeEntity(this.entityID);
            delete this;
        }
    }
}

    //Method to create a new entity//
function createNewEntity( entName,  sprite,   posX,  posY, HP){
    //snip!//
}

var damageField = new function(radius, power, posX, posY) {
//Damage any entities within a "square" radius of an entity. I plan to add radial version later//
//snip!//
}
this.init = function(){
    console.log("INIATING ENTS");
    createNewEntity("NUGGET", "chaingun_impact.png", 250, 250);
}
//update function for superclass update function to call//
this.update = function(){
    entity.updateEntity();
}
}
```

The main init function

```
function init(){
pushToSheetList();
jsonParser();
entities.init();
}
```

Also I am 99.99% sure that the update function is not called either it is the same code pretty much just update() instead.

I am really not sure what to do, unless I want to make it so every sprite on the screen is hard coded manually, and no one wants that for a reusable engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create instance of your `entities` class.

```
var oEntity=new entities();
oEntity.init();//call init method.
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, _for now_ , I'm not sure if for say I have a map class that contains map data, and there is a entity spawner if I were to call createNewEntity would actually work, I guess I will see later.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var en = new entities();
 en.init();
```